# Does the Death Curse also apply to animal companions?

Tags: dnd-5e, animal-companions, tomb-of-annihilation

My character, affected by the Death Curse, has a pet donkey he is really fond of and brings with him everywhere (protecting it from harm).

Is the donkey (or any animal companion that partakes in season 7 content) also affected by the Death Curse (unable to be resurrected, prone to surrogate rules and soul devouring, etc.), or does it only apply to player characters?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Tomb of Annihilation (p. 6) the Death Curse only applies to "humanoids" — your donkey (a beast) is safe.

Comment: Yeeeeeepeeeew! Shrek will live! (Yes, my donkey is called Shrek)

Comment: @GaelL Of course he is.